# Exporting Excel sheet to CSV - but exclude first 10 rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

[![Sheets in yellow I wish to ignore when I do the export, the Ws.rows command deletes the first 10 row but the vba script still exports all the sheets as CSV which I don't want, all the sheets have data in them. I have enclosed the the spreadsheet, the first page is the index, down the botton you will see the sheets, accom Price Overnight.

```
Sub ExportCSV()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim path As String

path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Rows("1:10").Delete
        If ws.Name <> "Document Control" And ws.Name <> "Index sheet" Then           
            'With ws
                ws.SaveAs filename:=path & "_" & ws.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
            'End With
        End If
    Next ws
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Now it's very unclear what do you want, do you want to exclude rows or sheets? what is "accom Price Overnight."? Please add screenshots to make clear what you really want.

Comment: Ok Sorry if this is confusing, its sheets. There are 20 sheets in this spreadsheet they all contain data, Accom Price overnight is 1 sheet, the page that you see is the sheet index, down the bottom of the spread sheet you will see the tabs, in the TAB (sheet there is data). I want to exclude the first 10 sheets when I do the export however I do want to export what's remaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save only part of a sheet.  You need to delete the range you don't need before exporting.
You won't loose the data as you have saved the original workbook.

```
ws.Rows("1:10").Delete
```

Comment: Thanks for that but I seem to be getting an error with that command when I try to run the export CSV

Comment: I've missed `"` from the code, now it should be ok.

Comment: Thanksyou however its still exporting the first 10 rows which are tables in the sheet index to folders where I would like to exclude the first 10 rows tables in the sheet index.

Comment: Sub ExportCSV()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Save

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim path As String

path = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)



    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Rows("1:10").Delete
        If ws.Name <> "Document Control" And ws.Name <> "Index sheet" Then
        
        
        
        
        
        
            'With ws
                ws.SaveAs filename:=path & "_" & ws.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
            'End With
        End If

Comment: what do you mean by "tables in the sheet index", could you please post some screenshots / sample files? Does it work correctly if you do the activity manually (delete rows and export to csv)?

Comment: Yeah it delete the first 10 rows however when I run the scripts it exports everything including the first 10 rows which are tables in an index, just would like to excluded the top 10 in the sheet index.

Comment: Yeah it deleted the first 10 rows however when I run the scripts it exports everything including the first 10 rows which are tables in an index, just would like to exclude the top 10 in the sheet index. When I go to my documents where they export  I see everything included the top ten rows I didn't want to export.  Each row is link to a table (tab within the same spreadsheet its data with some info in it) for eg one is called Accom Pricing Overnight, its got some data in it when I want to export I see it as a separate excel spreadsheet in my documents.

Comment: still: could you please post some screenshots / sample files? Does it work correctly if you do the activity manually (delete rows and export to csv)?

Comment: Yeah no problems, whats the best way of sending it to you, not sure if these dialog boxes can handle screen dumps

Comment: upload it somewhere (google, dropbox,..) and post the link in your question to enables also others to see it.

Comment: Hello If you refer to this link http://superuser.com/questions/841398/how-to-convert-excel-file-with-multiple-sheets-to-a-set-of-csv-files?answertab=active#tab-top, I guess the question is how to exclude the top (first10) sheets in 20., don't want the first 10 to copy

Comment: Should I open up another problem?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. You should edit the current question.

Comment: edited the current problem